# Finding undefined symbols in windows static lib

Tags: c, windows, static-libraries

Is there any way to find out the list of undefined symbols in windows static library compiled using VC6?

I know the nm command will list all the symbols in linux and symbols with a tag of "U" can be identified as undefined. But, how to do it Windows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use dumpbin.exe /symbols on the .lib file.  That lists all the symbols used, the external ones have the "External" prefix.

Comment: Does dumpbin lists the symbols for .lib file also? I think it works only for .dlls.

Comment: @Jay, yes it does, I verified before posting.  The switch for DLLs is /imports

Comment: Yes it does. I verified it too. Thanks for the answer. : )

Comment: dumpbin /exports will show the names of exported methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you install GNU binutils in WSL / MSYS2 / Cygwin you have nm and it understands the object file format of VC6 or later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know we could do this.